# Объект в классе

Tags: ооп, классы, php, объекты

Здравствуйте!
Есть класс page который расширяется так

```
Class index extends page
  {
    function index()
    {
     /* */ 
    }
    function category()
    {
      /* */
    }

  }
```

т.е новое расширение это новая страница на сайте.

Также существует класс с модулями к которым можно обращаться так

```
$module->open->view();
```

Я хочу сделать что бы этот объект можно было вызывать в своем классе.

```
Class index extends page
  {
    function index()
    {
     $module->open->view();
    }
    function category()
    {
      /* */
    }

  }
```

Но просто так это не сделать, как можно реализовать видемость данного объекта в классе?

***Дополнения/****/***
Извините немного не понимаю, только изучаю ООП.

Так открываю классы и определяю

```
     class modules
  {   
    function index()
    {}
  }

  $module = new modules;

      foreach ($modules as $value)
      {
       $patch = _DOC_ROOT_."/core/module/".$value.".php";

         if(file_exists($patch))
           {
             include_once($patch);
             $module->$value = new $value;
           }

      }

   var_dump($module); /** Выдает **/

/**object(modules)#1 (1) {
  ["open"]=>
  object(open)#2 (0) {
  }

}**/
```

Но я все равно не понимаю как через статичный хелпер вывести этот класс.

```
 Class open
  {
    public function view($a)
    {
      $patch = _DOC_ROOT_."/view/".$a.".php";
      include $patch;
    }
    public function model($a)
    {
      $patch = _DOC_ROOT_."/model/".$a.".php";
      include $patch;
    }
  }
```

В другом классе

Comment: У меня такое чувство, что сегодня хэшкод населён клонами, которые одновременно разными способами бьются в одну стену. По очереди. Всем нужны какие то простые варианты доступа к неизвестно чему.

Comment: @alex159 я сильно не вчитывался, но почитайте [эту тему](http://hashcode.ru/questions/299339/).
Я когда-то задавался подобным вопросом. Сначала пользовался решением который дали мне в ответе. Сейчас я немного усовершенствовал свой код и работает просто прекрасно - могу дать пару советов по моей структуре страниц.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Наверное не тему пишу, но вижу это здесь, потому здесь и задаю свой вопрос. Да, и искал, но ответа не нашел.
Что означает вот эта $module, $this, запись. Зачем ставится этот знак? С самой концепцией ООП знаком, почти понимаю. Полагаю это правила синтаксиса?

Comment: На каком это языке?

Comment: На русском. А почему вы спрашиваете? Вы же написали по-русски.

Comment: Надо же.... Как же я не догадался.... Исходный код на русском... Вы не чубайс случайно??

Comment: Если Вы имели в виду язык программирования, так и пишите - ЯП. На SO Вы можете кроме русского задать также вопросы на английском, испанском, французском и т.д.. Извините, но Ваш вопрос я не понял. "На каком это языке?" - на каком языке что?

Comment: Так что насчет ЯП в примере? Неужели вам прямо как компилятору, надо строго ставить вопрос? Ведь контекст располагает к пониманию вопроса! Да и ууже ответить можно было в предыдущем комменте. Сенсей.

Comment: @KhachaturMagakyan, В вопросе содержится метка `php`, речь идёт именно об этом ЯП. Естественно, `$` - это часть синтаксиса данного языка. Если вас интересует, что он значит, вы можете задать вопрос об этом или найти информацию в интернете.

Comment: Нет, спасибо. Я пока не разобрался в синтаксисе с++, искал кое что, вышел на этот пост и не сразу разобрался. Очередной непонятный символ поверг меня в очередной шок.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так не получится. $module надо где-то определить. В конструкторе класса, например.

```
class index extends page
{
   protected $_module;
   function __contruct() {
       $this->_module = какой то способ его получить
   }

   function index()
   {
     $this->_module->open->view();
   }
}
```

Ещё можно предположить, что модуль - он типа определился и не меняется. Тогда помогут прокси-методы, магические методы или статические хэлперы

```
class index extends page
{
   protected $_module;

   function _module() { // прокси-метод
       $this->_module = какой то способ его получить
       return $this->_module;
   }

   function index()
   {
     $this->module()->open->view(); // через прокси-метод
     // ... или
     ModuleHelper::open()->view(); // через статический хэлпер
   }
}

class ModuleHelper // статический хэлпер
{
    static public function open()
    {
        $module = какой то способ его получить
        return $module->open();
    }
}
```

Comment: дополнил ворос, ответьте пожалуйста